# How do i make audio load faster in jPlayer?

Tags: jquery, performance, audio, download, jplayer

I've customized one of the jPlayer's playlist examples.
Here's what I've got so far  http://www.checkmateband.net/CheckmatePlayer/

Everything works fine for me except that my audio files (mp3 or ogg) are pretty heavy and it takes them some time to load .
In average 4 to 5 MB each (mp3 files are 192 kbps encoded) .

I'm currently hosting on GoDaddy.

**How can I speed up the loading process?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on my broadband connection the music takes no longer than 1 second to kick in - perfectly acceptable.. but to speed things up you could

- publish at a lower bitrate (e.g. or 96kpbs or 128kbps).. this is standard practise anyway to avoid "giving away" high fidelity music.
- publish mono audio (half the download size)
- host your audio on a dedicated CDN, e.g. [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)

See [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/), [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) for more details on the benefits of using a CDN.

Comment: Thank you for your advise.Can you tell more about the third option ? I don't think I understand how exactly hosting my data on another domain can improve performance ?

Comment: Thank you. CDN looks like a good solution.No way there is a free CDN service somewhere hah ? :)

Comment: hmm, not sure but you can your site online for free using https://appharbor.com/ or http://www.heroku.com/.

Answer (score 0):

After a little while I've noticed that http://soundcloud.com/ have a great performance.
Furthermore , you can upload your music there for free and create your own customized player using their APIs here : http://developers.soundcloud.com/

So my Advice, if you want custom scalable audio player , use soundcloud !